# Create ARReferenceObject manually from a 3d model?

Tags: ios, 3d, augmented-reality, arkit

I want to recognize 3d objects from models I provide.
There is no way I can scan the objects because they are mounted on & inside aircraft engines...
But we do have the 3d models in fbx & obj & other formats.

Would it be possible to somehow convert these to ARReferenceObjects so we don't have to use Unity (it's working there...), but can use ios?

Comment: i think it is not possible you can not use it any where else but I am not sure about it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, you want the ability to scan the real world for a 3Dimensional object recognised from an 3D model. Apples ARKit on IOS have the ability to recognise objects in the real world based on 3D objects. Though, it do need the .arobject file that is created from a scan. Also, it is best suited for small objects, that fits on a table. Objects with strong textures is better to recognise compared to mono coloured parts. So this might not be the solution yet. Though, there is also Vuforia plugin, the overview don't mention the need for pre-scanning your object.
https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/features/overview.html

Comment: I wish... But I checked and checked and it seems ARKit recognises point-clouds, not objects.... If I'm wrong, please point me to the documentation where it says you can input a 3d model to recognise in the real world...